# Stuck on proving uniqueness of null element in posets

Tags: coq

I am trying to learn COQ, by implementing facts on Posets. While proving my first theorem I am stuck here.

```
Class Poset {A: Type} ( leq : A -> A -> Prop ) : Prop := {
    reflexivity: forall x y : A, x = y -> (leq x y);
    antisymmetry: forall x y : A, ((leq x y) /\ (leq y x)) -> x = y;
    transitivity: forall x y z :A, ((leq x y) /\ (leq y z) -> (leq x z))
}.

Module Poset. 
    Parameter A : Type.
    Parameter leq : A -> A -> Prop.
    Parameter poset : @Poset A leq.
    Definition null_element (n : A) := 
        forall a : A, leq n a.
    Theorem uniqueness_of_null_element (n1 : A) (n2 : A) : null_element(n1) /\ null_element(n2) -> n1 = n2.
    Proof.
      unfold null_element.
    Qed.

End Poset.
```

I am not sure how to proceed after this. Can someone help?

Comment: Just apply `antisymmetry` and you will be basically done. A step by step proof: `intros [h1 h2]. apply antisymmetry. split. apply h1. apply h2.` A more seasoned proof `now intros [h1 h2]; apply antisymmetry.`

Comment: This is lot simpler than what I did I suppose. But I don't understand this `now` though.

Comment: On a tangent: in Coq, it is more idiomatic to write e.g. `antisymmetry` as `forall x y : A, leq x y -> leq y x -> x = y`.

Comment: Ah, Effectively currying. I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it. 
This is what I did.

```
Proof.
  unfold null_element.
  intros [H1 H2].
  specialize H1 with n2.
  specialize H2 with n1.
  apply antisymmetry.
  split.
  - apply H1.
  - apply H2.
Qed.
```

Comment: No need to use `specialize`, `apply` is smart enough to compute a proper instantiation using matching.

Comment: `now intros; apply antisymmetry.` can handle the lemma as well. The `easy` tactics (`now <tactic>` stands for `<tactic>; easy`) is smart enough to split the goal and `apply` can extract conjuncts.